How can draw curve on y axis with help of latex?
Please anyone can help to draw this curve(shown in the picture) with two different line style with the help of tikzpicture? Thanks in advance

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, ext.topaths.arcthrough, decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2.2, yscale=1.2]  % Increase x-axis and decrease y-axis scales
    % Define the function (centered on the y-axis)
    \def\func{-(\x)^2 +4}  % Parabola opening downwards, vertex at (0, 6)
    
    % Define the bounds for the x-values
    \def\lowerbound{-2.5}
    \def\upperbound{2.5}
    
    % Draw the axes
    \draw[->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,7) node[above] {$y$};

    % Add ticks on the x-axis
    \foreach \x in {-2,-1,0,1,2,3} {
        \draw (\x,0.15) -- (\x,-0.15); % tick marks
    }
    % Add ticks on the y-axis
    \foreach \y in {-1,0,1,2,3,4,5} {
        \draw (0.15,\y) -- (-0.15,\y); % tick marks
    }

    % Draw the function (parabola centered on the y-axis)
    \draw[domain=\lowerbound:\upperbound,smooth,variable=\x,line width=0.5mm] 
        plot ({\x},{-(\x)^2 + 6});  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Perceive various segments as sin, cosine or parabola, which Tikz can draw. Change line options as needed

can't you just plot 3 times with different domains?

@cfr I did it right now after very hard work. Thank you

In my opinion you need to describe your disered curve mathematically.
Since I do not know, which function that exactly is, I thought about something like -sin(x) along the y-axis, which has an ampiltude of inv(-x² + 6) = +/- sqrt(6-x); with other words: 
% inv(-x² + 6) = +/- sqrt(6-x)  ---> "amplitude function"
% max(-x² + 6) = 6
\tikzset{trig format=rad}
\draw[domain=0:6,
smooth, red!55, line width=1mm, 
] plot ({sqrt(6-\x)*(-sin(\x))},{\x});          

This gives you a workaround for which you can adjust the finer details of your curve yourself.
And: as already mentioned in the comments, you can work domain-wise to set different line styles (dashed, dotted,...)

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, ext.topaths.arcthrough, decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2.2, yscale=1.2]  % Increase x-axis and decrease y-axis scales
    % Define the function (centered on the y-axis)
    \def\func{-(\x)^2 +4}  % Parabola opening downwards, vertex at (0, 6)
    
    % Define the bounds for the x-values
    \def\lowerbound{-2.5}
    \def\upperbound{2.5}
    
    % Draw the axes
    \draw[->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,7) node[above] {$y$};

    % Add ticks on the x-axis
    \foreach \x in {-2,-1,0,1,2,3} {
        \draw (\x,0.15) -- (\x,-0.15); % tick marks
    }
    % Add ticks on the y-axis
    \foreach \y in {-1,0,1,2,3,4,5} {
        \draw (0.15,\y) -- (-0.15,\y); % tick marks
    }

    % Draw the function (parabola centered on the y-axis)
    \draw[domain=\lowerbound:\upperbound,smooth,variable=\x,line width=0.5mm] 
        plot ({\x},{-(\x)^2 + 6});  
        
% inv(-x² + 6) = +/- sqrt(6-x)  ---> "amplitude function"
% max(-x² + 6) = 6
\tikzset{trig format=rad}
\draw[domain=0:6,
smooth, red!55, line width=1mm, 
] plot ({sqrt(6-\x)*(-sin(\x))},{\x});          

\draw[domain=0:2,
smooth, very thick, 
] plot ({sqrt(6-\x)*(-sin(\x))},{\x});       

\draw[domain=2:4,
smooth, thick, dashed, 
] plot ({sqrt(6-\x)*(-sin(\x))},{\x});       

\draw[domain=4:6,
smooth, thick, dotted, 
] plot ({sqrt(6-\x)*(-sin(\x))},{\x});       
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

